# How to use "qstat" and "grep" to list lines containing a range of numbers?

Tags: linux, grep, cluster-ssh, qsub

To monitor the job status in clusters, `qstat` is used to output lines like this

```
job-ID  prior   name       user         state submit/start at     queue                          slots ja-task-ID
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 146767 2.75000 REMD       xxxxxx      Rr    03/26/2021 10:58:17 Arya@node-c11b-027.kathleen.uc   160
 146811 2.75000 REMD       xxxxxx      r     03/26/2021 11:37:48 Arya@node-c11b-043.kathleen.uc   160
 146862 2.25862 REMD       xxxxxx      Rq    03/26/2021 06:24:39                                  160
 146911 2.19397 REMD       xxxxxx      Rq    03/26/2021 11:37:20                                  160
 146768 0.00000 REMD       xxxxxx      hqw   03/13/2021 14:47:35                                  160
 146769 0.00000 REMD       xxxxxx      hqw   03/13/2021 14:47:35                                  160
 146770 0.00000 REMD       xxxxxx      hqw   03/13/2021 14:47:36                                  160
```

The first element of each line is the job ID. Is there a way to show the lines for a particular range of jobs, e.g. how to only show the jobs from 146868 to 146927? It seems that `grep` is needed.

Answer (score 2):

While you could construct regexes to match a range of numbers, it's really not worth it. Better use some tool that can deal with numbers as numbers. E.g. in awk this is rather trivial. Here, `a` and `b` are the lower and upper limits respectively, and `$1` is the first field, by default split along white space.

```
$ qstat | awk -v a=146868 -v b=146927 '$1 >= a && $1 <= b {print}'
 146911 2.19397 REMD       xxxxxx      Rq    03/26/2021 11:37:20                                  160
```

(In ERE, the equivalent regex would be something like `146(86[89]|8[789][0-9]|9[01][0-9]|92[0-7])`, unless I made a mistake there, which is not unlikely. In BRE, it's impossible since there's no alternation.)

Comment: Do I need to have ```qstat```? Should it be```< file.txt``` or ```> file.txt```? I got  ```-bash: file.txt: No such file or directory``` message when using ```< file.txt```

Comment: @lanselibai, right, I focused on just the awk and implicitly assumed input from a file. To filter the output of some command, you'd use e.g. `qstat | awk ...` the same as you'd use `qstat | grep ...`. Of course you could do `qstat > file.txt` and then `awk ...  < file.txt`, or `grep ... < file.txt`

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution:

`qstat | fgrep "$(seq 146868 146927)"`